# Property '"siteKey"' is incompatible with index signature

Tags: captcha, cloudflare-turnstile

I have been to trying to use your ngx-turnstile library for integrating the captcha for our project. After installing the "npm install ngx-turnstile --save", I have included in the app.module.ts file and imported in the app.module imports Array. Immediately after installing it get this error displayed.

how we can solve this problem We wanted to try your library, but there is no proper documentation of how exactly it can be used in the angular project. There are a couple of examples, but those are not working.

here is the ng version

```
         _                      _                 ____ _     ___ 
        / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
       / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | | 
      / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | | 
     /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                    |___/
        
    
    Angular CLI: 15.2.10        
    Node: 14.21.2
    Package Manager: npm 6.14.17
    OS: win32 x64
    
    Angular: 15.2.10
    ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
    
    Package                         Version
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.10
    @angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.10
    @angular-devkit/core            15.2.10
    @angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.10
    @schematics/angular             15.2.10
    rxjs                            7.8.1
    typescript                      4.9.5




Error: node_modules/ngx-turnstile/lib/ngx-turnstile.component.d.ts:34:103 - error TS2344: Type '{ siteKey: { alias: "siteKey"; required: false; }; action: { alias: "action"; required: false; }; cData: { alias: "cData"; required: false; }; theme: { alias: "theme"; required: false; }; version: { alias: "version"; required: false; }; tabIndex: { ...; }; appearance: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property '"siteKey"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ alias: "siteKey"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

34     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgxTurnstileComponent, "ngx-turnstile", ["ngx-turnstile"], { "siteKey": { "alias": "siteKey"; "required": false; }; "action": { "alias": "action"; "required": false; }; "cData": { "alias": "cData"; "required": false; }; "theme": { "alias": "theme"; "required": false; }; "version": { "alias": "version"; "required": false; }; "tabIndex": { "alias": "tabIndex"; "required": false; }; "appearance": { "alias": "appearance"; "required": false; }; }, { "resolved": "resolved"; }, never, never, false, never>;
                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: sorry, i Could not understand what you are saying.

Comment: I say that stack overflow is not a customer service for any libraray